# What is wrong with my Database Connection?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am Trying to send my database this query, and it keeps getting me invalid input and I don't know what is wrong ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString =@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                     "INSERT INTO Customer(Name,Telephone,Address,[Register Date]) VALUES(" + v_name + "," + telephone + "," + address + "," + date + ")", connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                string result = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                MessageBox.Show("Region = " + result);
                MessageBox.Show("You have Registered Succesfully");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
                Form1 st = new Form1();
                st.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception or error message you get?

Comment: And what are the values of your parameters?

Comment: I bet string are not enclosed with single quotes. The code is also vulnerable to SQL Injection. Parameterizing the values is the best wy you can do.

Comment: Catching an exception and then printing out a generic error message is not a great idea.... Why don't your write at least _MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.Message)_

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong in your connection but I see a problem with how to execute your command.

[`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a data which is the first row of the first column. But your `INSERT` statement doesn't return *any* data. You need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Customer(Name,Telephone,Address,[Register Date]) 
                       VALUES(@name, @tel, @address, @date)";
   // Add your parameter values with SqlParameterCollection.Add() method.
   try
   {
       connection.Open();
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
        //
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the error is in ur qry.
if the db field is nvarchar then u should pass the value between ''.
your qry like as follow:

```
 "INSERT INTO Customer(Name,Telephone,Address,[Register Date]) VALUES('" + v_name + "','" + telephone + "','" + address + "','" + date + "')"
```

Comment: Sorry, what means "ur qry"?

Comment: ur qry means your query....